# Angular 2 Can’t get data from Rest Service

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api2

I’m new in Angular 2 and I’m playing with the environment to create some app. Doing the things like the site Angular.io says I’m able to create an Injectable Service and using it on my AppComponent but only If I read the data from the same .ts file like this.sourceData = {…}. If I get the json data from a Rest service the data is undefined

app.service.ts

```ts
Import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class WebService {
    private dataUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/home';
    constructor(private http: Http) { }
    getData() : Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get(this.dataUrl)
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
   }
    private extractData(res: Response) {
        let body = res.json();
        return body.data || {};
    }
```

app.component.ts

```ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { WebService } from './app.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
    providers: [WebService]

})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    errorMessage: string;
    theData: Object;
    constructor(private dataService: WebService) {}

    ngOnInit() { this.getDataFromService(); }
    getDataFromService() {
        this. dataService. getData ()
            .subscribe(
            myData => this.theData = myData,
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }    
}
```

app.component.html

```ts
<p> {{ theData. classroom.Id }}</p>
```

JSON from service

```ts
{
    "classroom": {
        "Id": "01",
        "totalStudents": "2",

        "Students": [{
            "Name": "Jhon",
            "age": "18"
        }, {
            "Name": "Doe",
            "age": "18"
        }],
        "Teachers": [{
            "Name": "Jane",
            "age": "38"
        }, {
            "Name": "Doe",
            "age": "35"
        }]
    }
}
```

Am I missing something when using Observables?
Thanks in advance

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: open your console, maybe you can see error about "CORS" in here.

Comment: It's not a CORS problem, that I already fixed it. The first error on the console it's: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property ' classroom' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.ngfactory.js:25:34)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:13612:21)

Comment: Can you try using the safe-navigation operator? Like this: `<p> {{ theData?. classroom?.Id }}</p>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call response.json(), it automatically grabs the data property from the ajax response and returns it, so remove your reference to .data in your extractData method.

```
getData() : Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get(this.dataUrl)
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
   }
    private extractData(res: Response) {
        return res.json();
        //return body.data || {};  // <-- this line needs to go
    }
```

FYI, because your extractData method is reduced to one line, most example (and real life) code will just inline that call in your map function

```
 getData() : Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get(this.dataUrl)
            .map(response => response.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);
   }
```

Comment: I've added to this on the app.component.html  <p> {{ theData?. classroom.Id }}</p> . This allows to wait for the data  a?.b.c which would short circuit further evaluation if a is null.